# Any command-line or batch cmd to concatenate multiple .msg files?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have 50 .msg files in one dir.
Is there a Windows command-line method to concatenate those files into a single file?
I am using Windows XP SP3.
I don't want to type the name of all files.

Comment: Do the filenames follow a specific, numbered format or are they random?

Comment: Though it isn't a command-line solution, Outlook's File > Save As option lets you export lots of messages to one .txt file. http://www.outlookextractor.com/2013/02/convert-outlook-email-text.html

Answer (score 1):

Just copy all files together, no other format considerations?

```
copy *.msg allfiles.msg
```

Note: it will say "1 file copied", because it copies all files into one file.

Comment: I tried this, but when I opened the resulting message file in Outlook, it only showed one message. Also, the file's size was less than all the files it should have copied, which  makes me think it didn't successfully copy all the data.

Comment: @jonnybot: I didn't say Outlook could open such a file. OP didn't specify that. If the message contain special characters, it may be safer to use the `/b` binary switch.

Comment: The /b flag seems to help; the resulting allfiles.msg file seems to contain all the data. And while I'm not sure that the .msg files the OP was dealing with were Outlook messages, that was the use case that brought me here. Seemed a worthy note for posterity, if not quite worthy of its own answer.